# fullpage JS animation on section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fullpage.js

i' m making a fullpage Js website and i have animations in evry sections of my page, and i want that my animation play when i'm on the section, so i know have an after render option in this plugin but i dont know how to syntax it for make the css animation play 
there is my code ( in this example i'm trying to get the animation of the line of the section2 play only when i' m on the section2)

```js
var smallCircles= ['top','right','bottom','left','top'];
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thPage', 'lastPage'],
    scrollingSpeed: 1000, 
       

   
       });
    });
```

```css
body {
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.fp-section {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align:center;
}

.fp-section.fp-table, .fp-slide.fp-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fp-tableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fp-scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.fp-notransition {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}



#line{
    position:absolute;
 width:340px;
 margin-top:20px;
 height:4px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
   -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -moz-animation-name: slidein;
      -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
}

 @-moz-keyframes slidein {
      from {
        margin-left:100%;
        width:300%
      }
      
      to {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:600%;
      }
    }

 @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
      from {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:0%
      }
      
      to {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:340px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>


  <div id="fullpage">
          
            <div class="section " id="accueil">
                <h2>section1</h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="don">
              <h2>section2</h2>
              <div id="line"></div>
 
          
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="tri">
           
                    <h2>3</h2>
             
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="recycle">
                    <h2>4</h2>

                    </div>
                    
    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M

That's ideal to deal with CSS animations, if you are looking for javascript or jQuery animations, then you should use the [callbacks provided by fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave`:

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        //using index
        if(index == 3){
            alert("Section 3 ended loading");
        }

        //using anchorLink
        if(anchorLink == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Section 2 ended loading");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i understand my problem is that i dont know how to write the code for make the css play when i m on the section :   something like if( index == 3 ){ $('media').css(0).play(); }  ...?    actually i make my animation with css and i want to call it with javascript for make it play to each section

Comment: Then you should start learning CSS and Javascript before trying to use them... Or ask for your specific questions rather than a general one. I have answered your question. If you have any other issues, you should open new questions for them.